# Adding function of ranking every student's score

Tags: c++, windows, rank

I just started working with dev c++ and computer languages at all because of my course
Now, could you please help with adding a function of ranking every student's score?
I already did average, total and now I just need it to show which rank belongs to each student. It doesn't have to be in ascending or descending order, instead simply showing which rank is whose based on the total value. I just need to open a text document with already prepared scores and names and then compiling will show rank

```
typedef struct {
    int number;
    TCHAR name[10];
    int kor;
    int math;
    int eng;
    int tot;
    float avg;

    void scoreCalculatorWithName(HWND hwnd, HWND hSrc, HWND hDst)
    {

        TCHAR buff[BUFF_SIZE];
        DWORD fileSize;
        char* tok;
        int stdNum;
        STUDENT_SCORE stdScore[MAX_STUDENT_NUM];
        fileSize = GetWindowText(hSrc, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
        buff[fileSize + 1] = NULL;
        stdNum = 0;
        tok = strtok(buff, "\r\n");
        while (tok != NULL) {
            sscanf(tok, "%d %s %d %d %d\r\n", &stdScore[stdNum].number, &stdScore[stdNum].name,
                &stdScore[stdNum].kor, &stdScore[stdNum].math,
                &stdScore[stdNum].eng, &stdScore[stdNum].rank);
            tok = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
            stdNum++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stdNum; i++) {
            stdScore[i].tot = stdScore[i].kor + stdScore[i].math + stdScore[i].eng;
            stdScore[i].avg = (float)stdScore[i].tot / 3;
        }

        TCHAR str[MAX_DATA_NUM];
        sprintf(buff, "%-s\t%-s\t%-s\t%-s\t%-s\t%-s\t%-s\r\n",
            "Number", "name", "Kor", "Math", "Eng", "Total", "Average");
        for (int i = 0; i < stdNum; i++) {
            sprintf(str, "%-d\t%-s\t%-d\t%-d\t%-d\t%-d\t%-.1f\r\n",
                stdScore[i].number, stdScore[i].name,
                stdScore[i].kor, stdScore[i].math, stdScore[i].eng,
                stdScore[i].tot, stdScore[i].avg);
            strcat(buff, str);
        }

        strcat(buff, "\r\n");
        SetWindowText(hDst, buff);
    }
```

Comment: you are mixing C i/o into C++ and on top you are using the windows api. Is this due to requirements of the task or is this just the way to read from a file you found somewhere online? This looks more complicated than it needs to be, unless you are actually aiming for a windows app (and perhaps other odd requirements)

Comment: Use a `std::vector<STUDENT_SCORE>` and the built-in sorting function. Also, this is only technically C++; it is littered with C-isms.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it's homework for my advanced computer programing course so yeah professor said that windows app is required.
Also, i think there is no mistakes so far because that is the code my professor wrote

Comment: Plenty of mistakes in your given code: 1) mixing IO with computation; 2) not checking the result of sscanf; 3) trivial buffer overflow (leading to a crash or code execution) if you enter a long enough name 4) using strcat in a loop (quadratic behavior) 5) despite claiming to be C++, this is just C code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign a rank to each student we first sort a vector of pointers to the students:

```
std::vector<STUDENT_SCORE *> ranked;
for (int i = 0; i < stdNum; i++) {
  ranked.emplace_back(&stdScore[i]);
}

std::sort(begin(ranked), end(ranked),
          [](STUDENT_SCORE * left, STUDENT_SCORE * right) { return left->tot > right->tot; });
```

We can then just assign the ranks:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stdNum; i++) {
  ranked[i]->rank = i+1;
}
```